# Ошибка при попытке привязать Inline клавиатуру к сообщению Aiogram

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

У меня есть следующая inline клавиатура:

```
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

cart = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
    inline_keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(text="➕ Добавить товар ➕", callback_data="add_product")
        ],
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(text="➖ Удалить товар ➖", callback_data="del_product")
        ],
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(text=" Оформить заказ ", callback_data="checkout")
        ]
    ]
)
```

И при попытке првязать её к сообщению

```
def get_cart(self, user_id):
    with self.connection:
        result = self.cursor.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE user_id = ?",
            (user_id,)
        ).fetchall()
        
        return result


def generate(cart: tuple) -> str:
        result = " Список товаров в корзине:"
        if len(cart) == 0:
            result += f"\n\n{' '*8}Корзина пуста."

        for index, item in enumerate(cart):
            result += f"\n\n{' '*8}{index+1}. {db.get_product_name(item[1])}:\n{' '*12}Цена: {item[2]}\n{' '*12}Размер: {item[3]}"
        return result


await message.answer(
    generate(db.get_cart(message.from_user.id)),
    reply_markup = cart
)
```

Получаеться следующая ошибка:

> error_handler.py [LINE:49] #ERROR    [2021-10-14 15:12:35,405]
> TelegramAPIError: Can't parse reply keyboard markup json object
> Update: {"update_id": 443549189, "message": {"message_id": 263,
> "from": {"id": 794782785, "is_bot": false, "first_name": "Иван",
> "last_name": "Токарюк", "username": "vania_tokaryuk", "language_code":
> "ru"}, "chat": {"id": 794782785, "first_name": "Иван", "last_name":
> "Токарюк", "username": "vania_tokaryuk", "type": "private"}, "date":
> 1634213555, "text": " Корзина "}} Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py",
> line 259, in process_update
> return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)   File "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py",
> line 116, in notify
> response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)   File "/home/ivan/Рабочий стол/Garment Go/handlers/users/cart.py", line 33,
> in cart
> await message.answer(   File "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/types/message.py",
> line 361, in answer
> return await self.bot.send_message(   File "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/bot.py",
> line 314, in send_message
> result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_MESSAGE, payload)   File
> "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/base.py",
> line 208, in request
> return await api.make_request(self.session, self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,   File
> "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py",
> line 140, in make_request
> return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())   File
> "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py",
> line 115, in check_result
> exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)   File "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/utils/exceptions.py",
> line 141, in detect
> raise cls(description) aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Can't parse reply keyboard markup json object

Причём у меня есть ещё одна клавиатура

```
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

settings = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
    inline_keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(text="⚙️ Настройки ⚙️", callback_data="settings")
        ],
    ]
)
```

И при попытке прикрепить её ошибок нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался найти решение в Гугле, но не нашёл.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```py
cart = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(
    InlineKeyboardButton(text="➕ Добавить товар ➕", callback_data="add_product"),
    InlineKeyboardButton(text="➖ Удалить товар ➖", callback_data="del_product"),
    InlineKeyboardButton(text=" Оформить заказ ", callback_data="checkout")
)
```

Comment: Не помогло. Но в любом случае спасибо.

Comment: Странно, киньте пожалуйста код функции generate и db.get_cart, где вы их вызываете: `generate(db.get_cart(message.from_user.id))`

Comment: def generate(cart: tuple) -> str:
        result = " Список товаров в корзине:"
        if len(cart) == 0:
            result += f"\n\n{' '*8}Корзина пуста."

        for index, item in enumerate(cart):
            result += f"\n\n{' '*8}{index+1}. {db.get_product_name(item[1])}:\n{' '*12}Цена: {item[2]}\n{' '*12}Размер: {item[3]}"
        return result

Comment: def get_cart(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute(
                "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE user_id = ?",
                (user_id,)
            ).fetchall()
            
            return result

Comment: Только не в комментарии, а в вопрос, читать невозможно

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
await message.answer(
    generate(db.get_cart(message.from_user.id),
    reply_markup = cart)
)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

# Создаю клавиатуру
cart = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
    inline_keyboard=[
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(text="➕ Добавить товар ➕", callback_data="add_product"),
            InlineKeyboardButton(text="➖ Удалить товар ➖", callback_data="del_product")
        ],
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(text=" Оформить заказ ", callback_data="checkout")
        ]
    ]
)

# Получаю корзину пользователя из бд
cart_items = db.get_cart(message.from_user.id)

# Генерирую сообщение
text = generate(cart_items)

# Отправляю сообщение и прикрепляю к нему клавиатуру
await message.answer(text=text, reply_markup=cart)
```

попробуй так. Если не выходит - либо ошибка запроса, либо ошибка каллбеков